# Animate Rectangle so it goes up/down

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have created a line on my camera which is simple `Rectangle()` and now I'm stuck where I want to make it move up and down. Line should move from top camera container to bottom and vice versa so it simulates scanner.

I suppose that could me made by moving `Rectangle()` on `y` axis providing positive values until scanner hits defined `position` then providing negative values to `y` until again reaches defined position with constant or infinite repeating.

Maybe this is simple but I'm still new in SwiftUI and iOS generally so I don't know how to do this.

Here is an image of how it looks like now:
[image]

And here is the code:

```
VStack {
    Spacer()
    BackgroundView()
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 15, trailing: 0))
    ZStack {
        CBScanner(supportBarcode: [.ean8, .ean13, .upce])
            .interval(delay: 2.0)
            .found{
          // barcode found other code
        }
        Rectangle()
        .trim()
        .background(ColorsStatic.redish)
            .foregroundColor(ColorsStatic.redish)
            .frame(width: 350, height: 1)
    }.frame(width: 350, height: 180)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var animating = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .trim()
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: 350, height: 1)
                    .offset(y: animating ? 90 : -90)
                    .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever())

            }.frame(width: 350, height: 180)
            .onAppear {
                self.animating.toggle()
            }
            .background(Color.green)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I appreciate that. It does work which is great but, for some reason rectangle will move just around 1/3 of space instead through whole camera container (top/bottom vice versa). Right now it goes from middle to bottom and back to middle. 
I tried to change values for  `y` in `offset` but can not expand space of movement.

Comment: I figure it out: `Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever()` should go as parameter `withAnimation`